# Почему не выполняеться перевод двойных букв в данной программе?

Tags: php

```
<?php

// Транслитерация строк. 
function transliterate($st) { 
  $st = strtr($st, array( 
    "ё"=>'yo',    "х"=>'h',  "ц"=>'ts',  "ч"=>'ch', "ш"=>'sh',   
    "щ"=>'shch',  "ю"=>'yu', "я"=>'ya', 
    "Ё"=>'Yo',    "Х"=>'H',  "Ц"=>'Ts',  "Ч"=>'Ch', "Ш"=>'Sh', 
    "Щ"=>'Shch',  "Ю"=>'Yu', "Я"=>'Ya'
  )); 
  $st = strtr($st,
    "abvgdegziyklmnoprstufeABVGDEJZIYKMNOPRSTUFIE",
    "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфэАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФЫЭ"
  ); 
  return $st; 
}

$dir = opendir ("akkordy/"); //путь к файлам

while ( $file = readdir ($dir)) 
{ 
if (( $file != ".") && ($file != "..") && ( $file != "index.php"))

{
$z = transliterate($file);
echo '<img src="/gitara/themes/present/images/PostCategoryIcon.png" WIDTH="50" HEIGHT="50" alt=""><a href="akkordy/'.$file.'">'.basename("$z", "зип").PHP_EOL.zip.'</a><br>';
} 
} 
closedir ($dir);

?>
```

Все файлы переводит на русский, но как я понимаю
эта часть программы не работает так как двойные **я, ю,**  раскладываются **как йа,** йу,

```
 $st = strtr($st, array( 
            "ё"=>'yo',    "х"=>'h',  "ц"=>'ts',  "ч"=>'ch', "ш"=>'sh',   
            "щ"=>'shch',  "ю"=>'yu', "я"=>'ya', 
            "Ё"=>'Yo',    "Х"=>'H',  "Ц"=>'Ts',  "Ч"=>'Ch', "Ш"=>'Sh', 
            "Щ"=>'Shch',  "Ю"=>'Yu', "Я"=>'Ya'
          ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему бы вам просто не задействовать регистронезависимую функцию:

```
str_ireplace(<что менять>,<на что>,<где>);
```

Вот так:

```
$cat = "aaaaabsaddabdbabd";  // строка, подлежащая частичной замене
$r=array("a","b");           // что менять ("a" и "b");
$r2=array("0","1");          // на что менять ("0" и "1");
echo str_ireplace($r,$r2,$cat);
```

**В итоге все символы "a" в строке будут заменены на "0", а все символы "b" на "1".**

Comment: А почему бы вам просто не задействовать функцию:?
Потому, что я не волшебник, я только учусь.

Comment: Ну помогло-то или нет?

Comment: Работает!Спасибо!!!

Comment: Пожалуйста =)

Answer (score 2):

У вас переменная **`$st`** вызывает два раза функцию **`strtr();`**

Когда функция выполняется первый раз, она преобразовывает `"Ю"=>'Yu'`

Следом функция выполняется второй раз и преобразовывает **Y** на **Й** а **u** на **у**, в итоге получается Йу!

Надеюсь доступно объяснил!

Используйте подход:

```
 $st = strtr($st, array( 
            "ё"=>'yo',    "х"=>'h',  "ц"=>'ts',  "ч"=>'ch', "ш"=>'sh',   
            "щ"=>'shch',  "ю"=>'yu', "я"=>'ya', 
            "Ё"=>'Yo',    "Х"=>'H',  "Ц"=>'Ts',  "Ч"=>'Ch', "Ш"=>'Sh', 
            "Щ"=>'Shch',  "Ю"=>'Yu', "Я"=>'Ya'
          ));
```

Для преобразования всех букв! Код получится больше, но работать будет эфективнее!

Comment: Ясно...!!!